# Python - Celery task call other function doesn't work?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I can't seem to call other functions within a [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) scheduled task. The task fires on a delay of 10 seconds after main program start.  Using rabbitmq as the broker.

I'm testing two calls within the task:

- log a message using standard logger - with the task: nothing is logged to the log file
- download the zen of python to a txt file on disk - with the task: no file is downloaded

The main program:

```
import mytasks
import utilities
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    utilities.start_message("log: program started")
    print("program started")
    mytasks.test_message.apply_async(countdown=10)
    sleep(3000)
```

task module:

```
from celery import Celery
import utilities

celery = Celery(__name__,
                broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
                backend='amqp://guest@localhost//')


@celery.task
def test_message():
    utilities.display_message("hello")
    utilities.acquire_zen()
```

utilities module, called by task:

```
import logging
import urllib.request

logging.basicConfig(filename="message.log",
                    filemode="w",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


def start_message(message):
    logging.info(message)


def display_message(message):
    final_message = "test message: " + message
    logging.info(final_message)
    return ("terminal message" + message)


def acquire_zen():
    url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/baccenfutter/61c5eb9c482df4200611/raw/5acfab2350116f076f47b44cb991950b3e1db7c8/zen-of-python.txt"
    fo = open('python_zen.txt', 'w')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        s = u.read()
    fo.write(str(s))
    fo.close()
```

Celery terminal output:

```
[2016-03-11 03:46:56,956: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2016-03-11 03:46:56,967: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-03-11 03:46:57,978: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-03-11 03:46:57,993: WARNING/MainProcess] XX@YYYYY.local ready.
[2016-03-11 04:06:25,801: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mytasks.test_message[cef363cb-cef6-4b2a-b2a0-7b06f05e933a] eta:[2016-03-10 17:06:35.789261+00:00]
[2016-03-11 04:06:35,806: INFO/Worker-4] test message: hello
[2016-03-11 04:06:35,858: INFO/MainProcess] Task mytasks.test_message[cef363cb-cef6-4b2a-b2a0-7b06f05e933a] succeeded in 0.051920230966061354s: None
```

Right now, the celery output is due to the `return final_message` statement. The message is not actually added to the log. Nor is the python_zen.txt downloaded. Whereas, if I called those functions without scheduling them in Celery, they work fine.

What am I doing wrong with Celery?

Comment: The log output you have posted seems consistent with the code your posted. "I can't seem to call other functions within a Celery scheduled task." The first function you call (`display_message`) makes a logging call which is clearly visible in the log output. The second call (`acquire_zen`) doesn't log or print anything. The celery task then succeeds. What is the problem?

Comment: "Right now, the celery output is due to the return final_message statement." Why do you think that? It looks to me like that function is called by `utilities.display_message("hello")` in the task, and the return value is simply lost because it's no assigned anywhere. "The message is not actually added to the log." But as I said above, that message is in the log (`[2016-03-11 04:06:35,806: INFO/Worker-4] test message: hello`). Maybe if you make the function log a different message than what it returns, you will be able to prove who is correct?

Comment: I modified my original question by changing `return` to `return ("terminal message" + message)`. Celery terminal output still shows `test message: hello`. I'm even more confused now as to why `logging.info(final_message)` is outputting to terminal, instead of the actual log (log is never created)?  p.s. python_zen.txt is created :D

Comment: you need to read up on celery workers - they basically take over the top level python logger, which is why you are seeing log messages going to the terminal and no log file being created. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging - I have found this to be a major pain in the past, it is very fiddly to completely override the celery workers 'helpful' log setup features.